# Can I safely trim civicrm_job_log and civicrm_log?

Tags: logs, 4.6

`civicrm_job_log` is the biggest table in my database by an order of magnitude. And `civicrm_log` is the fifth biggest.

Can I trim these somehow, e.g. a cron job that removes old logs? It's making the backups slow.

### EDIT: Here's an extension that keeps the job log from bloating

Thanks to the input here, I've created the [Log Lop extension](https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.artfulrobot.loglop) that allows users to configure a maximum age for keeping job logs. Will submit to the extensions directory after a bit more testing/few more eyes have looked at it.

Comment: In fact, that extension isn't necessary or a good idea either, just enable the core system job "Clean-up Temporary Data and File" [as noted when you click through to that extension].

Comment: Thanks @AlanDixon

Comment: Ah, but thank you for posting the original issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can safely trim the civicrm_job_log, only the latest entries are probably useful (and given how little information the cronjobs return, I'd even doubt that ;)

As for the civicrm_log (or subscription history), it might be more risky to remove as you will loose "useful" history of what happened with your contacts, but from a technical point of view, it shouldn't be an issue, as long as you are ok losing that history.

Comment: Thanks, Xavier. Yeah I think I can live with not knowing that a record was changed some time in 2003, so I'll set up a cronjob to keep these tables trim. Many thanks.

Comment: Would be awesome if you would write an extension that provides a browser interface (using the api) for that trimming, ideally with a param to set the cut off date (eg delete everything that is older than "delta" days ago)

Comment: What if said extension "archived" the "useful" history from civicrm_log to a separate table, or .sql file?

Comment: Is it safe to trim civicrm_log? Since it stores a change history, by removing some of the first rows you might be removing original values?

Comment: the latest version is always stored into the "real" entity (eg. civicrm_contact). The log mostly doesn't contain any data per se, only meta data (bob changed the contact on the 1st of april last year)

Comment: @Xavier Could you take a look at this? https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.artfulrobot.loglop

Comment: Looks good, but please https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.artfulrobot.loglop/blob/master/api/v3/JobLog/Loglop.php#L36 don't return success when it's clearly a failure, throw an error

Answer (score 3):

Truncate civicrm_job_log as often as you like - the data is only of very very marginal interest and only for a short period

I usually prefer to turn on DB logging - in which case the data in the civicrm_log table doesn't really add anything - it's only a little bit useful IMHO anyway.