# No run_time timestamp in civicrm_job_log

Tags: mysql, logs, scheduled-job

Currently, my civicrm_job_log is the largest table in our database. There was a post [Can I safely trim civicrm_job_log and civicrm_log?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10239/can-i-safely-trim-civicrm-job-log-and-civicrm-log) that mentioned an extension that would keep this table trimmed based on an age. However, in my civicrm_job_log all the run_time timestamps are NULL. How can I get these recorded correctly so that I can keep this log trimmed? fwiw, the timestamps in civicrm_log, noting changes to the database, are filled in correctly [this is also a rather bloated table that I would like to trim]. So, two questions [sorry]

1. How do I get non-NULL run_times in my job log table?
2. How can I best manage civicrm_log and civicrm_job_log?

Comment: I might add that in Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs, if I go to ANY job and View Job Log, the Date column is blank, just as observed by looking at the database directly. The date-time the last job was run is correct. It is just not being inserted into the database. Is there a function that does it? Does it rely on any stored MySQL routines in the database itself? I have imported MySQL backups on a few occasions as we work through a few glitches in our first CiviCRM setup. Although, I'm sure the DB structure and tables are getting filled in, perhaps I lost something along the way?

Answer (score 1):

Funny thing, while the Date column is filled out with a value in CiviCRM 4.6, it is empty in CiviCRM 4.7. I have checked on my customer's instances and the run_time column is in fact present but empty on 4.7. I will file a JIRA issue on this topic.

If your main concern is cleaning-up this table, you can easily do this by only keeping the last 1,000 or so entries in this table. This is easily done as the civicrm_job_log table, like many CiviCRM table, as an id column that is auto-increment. So you would do this to keep that last 1,000 entries:

`-- from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578867/sql-query-delete-all-records-from-the-table-except-latest-n/8303440#8303440
DELETE FROM`civicrm_job_log
  `WHERE id <= (
    SELECT id
    FROM (
      SELECT id
      FROM`civicrm_job_log
      `ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1000 -- keep this many records
    ) foo
  );`

Comment: I was planning to use the id to keep the last 1000 entries. I appreciate the reference to the exact query to do that. Seems like that should be part of the cleanup function that we schedule daily. How can I track the JIRA issue?

Comment: JIRA issue is probably this one https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20165 Nicolas at cividesk, can you confirm?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks @TwoMice.